# SMTP Relay/Redirect Proxy

Tags: python, node.js, email, smtp

I need to relay an email received to an SMTP server to multiple other emails.  I would like to keep all the original content, header, from email and ip address.  Is this possible and what service or open source software can I use for this?  I'd like to have an API option, don't care about spam filter or anything else, I only need a simple relay/redirect.

Example:

Email A from SenderA is sent to SenderB (SMTP Proxy)

SenderB (SMTP Proxy) redirects email to SenderC and SenderD

Comment: what did you try? Did you check any mail providers if they have function like this? Don't expect that we will search it for you.

Comment: if server uses `SMTP` and `POP` (or better `IMAP`) then you could write script which checks if there is new mail on server and resend it to other users. And you have to only run this program periodically. Python has standard module [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html), [poplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/poplib.html), [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html) but external module like [imapclient](https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.0/) can be simpler to use.

Comment: Just set the additional receiver as CC in the e-mail. (or BCC)